# Displaying Plone folder_rename_form with Diazo

Tags: ajax, overlay, plone, diazo

I have `<notheme if="$ajax_load" />` in rules.xml, but I find that I also have to add `<notheme if-path="folder_rename_form/" />` so that the rename overlay from the Actions menu will display. But with this rule, if I go to folder_contents, select an item and hit rename from there, I get an unthemed page.  What rule can I use to have the rename working properly in both places?

I am pulling in everything from #portal-column-content, so #content is there.

Comment: Is your ruleset skipping cases where #visual-portal-wrapper is missing?

Comment: no, it's wrapped in <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">

Comment: OK, any chance that the code to activate that particular overlay has been customized?

Comment: I've just hit this problem too (Plone 4.3), and I have a sense of Deja vu about it.

What I've found is that there is no `ajax_load` field in the rename form.  and that's what the Diazo variable is looking for.

Comment: reported as an issue https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1628